# Generate a consolidated log from multiple remote processes

Tags: python, logging

I have script that spawns another script on several hosts on a network. These scripts generate output that I want to capture. So the only option I can see right now is this:

*Log each process' output in a separate file (like 20130308.hostname.log, etc).*

Is there a way to generate a consolidated log out of all the processes? By consolidated I mean something like this:

```
host1:
outputline1
outputline2

host2:
outputline1
outputline2
outputline3

host3:
...
```

I want to be able to open one file - and check up on what happened on a particular host.

Comment: What have you tried? Should we write a script going through your logs and creating a single one? What do you expect? Is there a way? Yes, with your brain and your favorite Python editor....

Comment: @PrincessOftheUniverse I just have separate log files for each process. I'm looking for something better to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you want to have several processes log into one file. There are better option then the one you suggest, please check the python [logging cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html). 'Multiple modules' and 'multiple handlers' should to solve your issue.

Comment: even as poor as the OPs question. Only a centralized logging system like syslog can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a centralized logging system like syslog for aggregating all logging messages into a central log. Python's logging module provides a SyslogHandler for that.

For aggregating individual logfiles into one logfile manually you will have to write a script performing the aggregation and merging.